# Is it possible for an ios app to send all request to firebase through proxy?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, proxy

I have an IOS app that uses a Firebase SDK. I would like it to send every request to *.googleapis.com through my proxy.

Maybe there is a way to make every request of the app go through a proxy?